# Is there a way to get legal moves for the person whos turn its not? python-chess

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess, python-chess

I am interested in making a chess algorithm. For this, I will be using the python-chess library. However, to make a good algorithm I need to be able to return the opposing persons legal moves even if it isn't their turn.
So in the start of the game it would return

board.legal_moves() -> [A2A4, A2A1, B2B4, B2B1, ect...]

I was wondering if during the start of the game I could say something like

board.enemy_legal_moves() > [A7A5, A7A6, ect...]

or if there is any algorithmic way I could do it.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: "However, to make a good algorithm I need to be able to return the opposing persons legal moves even if it isn't their turn." - no you don't.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to keep track of the legal moves in a list from the beginning of the game:

```
legal_moves = []

current_legal_moves = board.legal_moves()
legal_moves.append(current_legal_moves)
```

Then you can simply get the list of your enemy's legal moves by:

```
enemy_legal_moves = legal_moves[-1]
```

This will obviously not work if you want to call this for the first move in the game. If you really need to do that, then you can either:

1. From the start position switch to black and run the board.legal_moves(). Then take this list and add as start value like this: `legal_moves = [black_legal_moves_start_pos]`
2. Write the list of blacks 20 first legal moves from the start position and add it to `legal_moves` as in option 1 above.